# How can I fix the "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, screen

So, here is the Navigation Container I've created:

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Music" component={MusicScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

But I don't need to button be unique on each screen, there will be 3 buttons which will display at all screens. So here is my map function where I map through all of my buttons:

```
{tabs.map(({ icon, line }, index) => (
                <View key={ index }>
                  <Tab 
                    {...{ index, transition, active }}
                    onPress={() => {
                      active.setValue(index);

                      if (index == 0) {
                        navigation.navigate('Music')
                      } else if (index == 1) {
                        navigation.navigate('Home')
                      } else if (index == 2) {
                        navigation.navigate('Profile')
                      }
                    }}
                  >
                    {icon}
                  </Tab>
                  <View style={styles.blueLineContainerBack}>
                    <LineWrapper
                      {...{activeTransition, active, line, index}}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              ))}
```

While I'm pressing at a button I'm getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') error. How can I fix that?

Comment: sounds like you want to use tab navigation instead of stack navigation. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation

Comment: Not really, cause I already tried this and that's not working properly

Comment: I think you can use withNavigation(componentName) to use navigation props in this component.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note that `navigation` is only defined within the screens components.
Within your onPress function, call the useNavigation hook to have access to navigation. Something like this should work:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

And you need to import it from React Navigation as such:

`import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in one of 'Screens' that you defined (Home, Profile, Music) you, the React-Navigation library passes the 'navigation' prop into them. So you should use it like below:

```
props.navigation.navigate('Music');
```

If that fails too, you can use [react navigation Hooks](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop) to access the navigation object like this:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
const MyComponent = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  ...
  return(
    ...
    <Button title="Go to music" onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Music'); }} />
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```